# O que é o ReactPHP , para que serve, vale a pena utilizar?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber o que é o  [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/).
Não encontrei nenhum material explicando o que é e qual é o seu objetivo.

Gostaria de saber para que serve e se vale a pena utilizar.

Comment: No SOen há essa resposta relacionada à sua: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24067776/1432957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REactPHP é uma biblioteca de baixo nível para programação orientada a eventos em PHP.

No seu núcleo está um loop de eventos, em cima do qual fornece utilitários de baixo nível, tais como: abstração de fluxos, resolução DNS assíncrona, cliente / servidor de rede, cliente / servidor http, interação com processos.

Bibliotecas de terceiros podem usar esses componentes para criar clientes / servidores de rede assíncrona e muito mais.

Exemplo de uso:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = function ($request, $response) {
    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end("Hello World\n");
};

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

$http->on('request', $app);
echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337\n";

$socket->listen(1337);
$loop->run();
```

Veja também: http://reactphp.org/